# How to understand JavaScript async functions using traditional Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I think I understand Promises 99% well: it basically is "similar" to an observer pattern, which says, "when value is ready, notify me (call the callback function I give to you)", except you can subscribe to it late, and it'd still notify you, and that it happens only once.

However, when I get to `async function()`, I sometimes get confused: the `await` is not really a "wait". It is more like a `notifyMeLaterWhenReady`. And when we call an async function, it is like it returns right away, giving back a promise that is resolved at the very end when it reaches the end of this async function. (or when it returns something early).

It is like:

```js
async foo() => {
  const a = await bar();
  const b = await wah(a);
  return lala(a, b);   // lala is a regular function (not async)
}
```

is equivilent to

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a, b;

    bar()
      .then(v => { a = v; return wah(a); })
      .then(v => { b = v; resolve(lala(a, b)); });
  };
}
```

Is this how to understand an async function and a near perfect translation of async function to a Promise paradigm?  It is only after it is translated I feel I understand it 99%. (with some complication of `catch`, `finally`, and `throw`, `try`, `catch` which I sometimes ignore, as many of my coworkers don't do error handling but just assume it is the network down and there is nothing the code can do about it).

Comment: Maybe this will help.   https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: I think that's basically it. You could try using Babel.js to transpile code that uses `await` and see what the result code is.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno the line there "The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result" that one is quite confusing... "there is no wait" (no blocking)

Comment: An async function is essentially syntactic sugar for working with Promises, making the code more readable and easier to write.

Comment: Take a look at the transpiled JS code in the panel on the right at this TypeScript playground link — this is how TS downlevels it to ES2015: https://tsplay.dev/Wox8Mw

Comment: What's the actual question? (Questions on this site need to have an objective answer — see [ask].)

Answer (score 1):

The translation is almost complete but lacks a `catch` clause for completeness:

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a, b;

    bar()
      .then(v => { a = v; return wah(a); })
      .then(v => { b = v; resolve(lala(a, b)); })
      .catch(reject); // Reject the promise returned
  };
}
```

- If a promise operand of the `await` operator rejects, `await` throws the error.
- If the value thrown is not caught inside the `async` function using a traditional `try/catch` construct, the value is used (by `async` function native code) to reject the Promise object returned when the function was called.

---

Under the hood:

1. `await` only returns the successfully settled value of a promise operand - or the actual value of a non-promise operand. If specific error processing is needed you can use a `try/catch` construct around the `await promise` statement, or start using promise chains with `catch` clauses within the `async` function (which seems a little odd).
2. `finally` clauses would need to be explicitly chained to promise values within the `async` body proper, or depending on the specific case possibly added to the promise returned from the async function.
3. Calling an async function executes synchronously until

- a return statement is executed. The function caller is (synchronously) returned the equivalent of `Promise.resolve(returnValue)`
- an error is thrown. Unless caught by `try/catch`, the function caller is (synchronously) returned the equivalent of `Promise.reject( thrownValue)`.
- an `await` operator is executed. The function caller is synchronously returned a pending promise. `await` fudges the call stack to resume execution of calling code after  it makes a copy of its calling context and returns to the event loop pending settlement of the awaited promise.