# Does this code run synchronously? Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I understand that Axios runs asynchronously in Javascript. Also, I understand that Axios runs synchronously if I use Axios, async, and await together.

```js
const test = async () => {
  const first = await axios.get("some url");
  const second = await axios.get("some other url");
  const third = await axios.get("some other other url");
};
```

Then in this code, is it correct that the first function is executed and the task is finished, the second function is executed and the task is finished, and then the third is executed?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: One would expect that to be the case, yes.  When you test this, what happens?

Comment: @David I don't know how to look at the order of execution. But this code seems to be running as you think it is! Thank you!

Comment: No, this code runs asynchronously. 
async/await make it only looks like it is synchronous.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await

Comment: @RidgeA: True, and likely a distinction worth noting.  @Odriv: The code doesn't run *synchronously*, and also depends on whether `test()` itself is awaited.  But within `test()` these three operations will run *asynchronously* but *"in serial"* with each operation being awaited.

Comment: Specifically, " Also, I understand that Axios runs synchronously if I use Axios, async, and await together" is a misunderstanding on your part. Please investigate further.

Comment: @Odriv A not-foolproof way to check is to put a `console.log` between each axios call. You'll see the network delay between logs. W/o awaiting they'll print immediately.

Comment: the code in that function runs sequentially (given there's no rejections of course)

Comment: Please realise that a function **returns** when it has evaluated the expression given to an `await` operator. The rest of the function's code will only get executed later, when the corresponding promise resolves -- that is to say *asynchronously*. In the meanwhile, other JavaScript code can continue to execute.

Comment: I recently looked at how much of an `async` function runs synchronously when called. If you're interested have a look at point 3 of "under the hood" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267915/5217142). It's not hugely technical but may be of some help.